# Double click in Firefox: Select whole path, dont't stop at slash

Tags: firefox, double-click

If I double click on "bar" in a path like "/foo/bar" in firefox only "bar" gets selected. In gnome terminal it works the way I like it: the whole path gets selected.

How can I modify firefox to select the whole path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting "layout.word_select.stop_at_punctuation".

The default is "true". If you set it to "false". Now double click won't stop at underscores or slashes.

Set it like this: type about:config in the address bar, hit [ENTER]. Then enter the first chars of the variable, modify it, done.

You can change this setting in thunderbird like this:
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor (button)"

Comment: That looks nice. I've often wondered about that myself, being a 2-OS user (Windows at work, Linux at home). Can you say why the default setting would be different between Windows and Linux?